# Check ping statistics without stopping

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu, ping

Is there a way to tell `ping` to show its usual termination statistics without stopping the execution?

For instance, I'd like to quickly view:

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2410 packets transmitted, 2274 received, +27 errors, 5% packet loss, time 2412839ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 26.103/48.917/639.493/52.093 ms, pipe 3
```

without having to stop the program, thus losing the accumulated data.

Comment: Indeed, as Andreas suggests above, you can use CTRL+\ to get the statistics without quitting ping.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the `ping` manpage (emphasis mine):

> When the specified number of packets have been  sent (and  received)  or  if  the program is terminated with a SIGINT, a brief summary is displayed. **Shorter current statistics can be obtained without termination of process with signal SIGQUIT.**

So this will work if you're fine with your stats being slightly less verbose:

```
# the second part is only for showing you the PID
ping 8.8.8.8 & jobs ; fg

<... in another terminal ...>

kill -SIGQUIT $PID
```

Short statistics look like this:

```
19/19 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 0.068/0.073/0.074/0.088 ms
```

Comment: One slight addition: You can emit `SIGQUIT` from the terminal by hitting "Ctrl-\", no need to have a second terminal open and use `kill`.

Comment: Also, on BSD variants (including OSX), ping summarizes with a SIGINFO signal, which can be triggered with Ctrl-T in the terminal.

Comment: I regularly have multiple terminals going with continuous `ping`s going.  I usually start `while true; do ps -o "pid" -C "ping" h | xargs kill -SIGQUIT; sleep 20; done &` in the first terminal before starting the `ping`.  This allows me to start new `ping`s and/or restart existing `ping`s (to reset stats) and not need to track `PID`s for `kill`.

Comment: Using this method means there is no need to use the `& jobs ; fg` part of the command in the answer since it's only purpose is reporting the `PID`... Sorry for the additional comment - can't edit my original comment anymore due to the 5 minute threshold.

Comment: @StarsonHochschild, I would propose you to post your method as new answer.

Comment: Thank you for the inspiration, @VictorYarema.  I have submitted my method as an answer, ported it to FreeBSD, and tried to compile all of the info in the various other answers and comments into one place.

Answer (score 24):

There is one more easy way to get the ping statistics durning it's execution:
Just press **Ctrl + |** (vertical slash or it's also called pipe line)

I do personally use it very often, try it:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.893 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=0.862 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=3.18 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=35 ttl=64 time=0.877 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=36 ttl=64 time=0.866 ms
**36/36 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 0.832/0.993/0.930/3.185 ms**
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=0.909 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=2.03 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=39 ttl=64 time=0.839 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=0.880 ms
```

Comment: In a twist of fate, I actually contributed some code toward that particular feature after getting my answer from the selected best answer.

Comment: I'm surprised to see that, for me in Ubuntu Bionic running Terminal, according to xev, `Ctrl + \ ` is the same as the key combination mentioned in other answers here: `Ctrl + |` and `Ctrl + 4`.  All yield an XLookupString of 0x1c which is bound to SIGQUIT as shown by `stty -a`.  See also [keyboard shortcuts - Shell SIGKILL Keybinding - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/288772/shell-sigkill-keybinding)

Answer (score 10):

On **Mac** it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> does the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, as it stops the ping after showing the stats.

Comment: Kudos to @brian-clide, just noticed he answered before me in a comment.

Comment: CTRL-4 works for me on mac

Answer (score 10):

## Linux (Tested on Ubuntu 20.04)

Send the `SIGQUIT` signal.

Example output:

```
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=138 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=139 ttl=64 time=0.022 ms
139/139 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 0.014/0.022/0.022/0.057 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=140 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=141 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
```

### Send while running

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> = `quit` according to `stty -a`.
These also work: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>;

### Send to one or more known pids

```bsh
kill -SIGQUIT <pid> [...]
```

### Send to all running

```bsh
ps -o pid= -C ping | xargs -r kill -SIGQUIT
```

### Periodically send to all running

```bsh
while sleep 20; do ps -o pid= -C ping | xargs -r kill -SIGQUIT; done
```

#### As a background job

```bsh
while sleep 20; do ps -o pid= -C ping | xargs -r kill -SIGQUIT; done &
```

---

## FreeBSD (Tested on pfSense 2.4.5, based on FreeBSD 11.3)

Send the `INFO` signal.

Example output when sent via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=137 ttl=64 time=0.328 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=138 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
load: 0.18  cmd: ping 62483 [select] 144.69r 0.00u 0.01s 0% 2256k
139/139 packets received (100.0%) 0.018 min / 0.072 avg / 0.505 max
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=139 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=140 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
```

Example output when sent via `kill`:

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=137 ttl=64 time=0.328 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=138 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
139/139 packets received (100.0%) 0.018 min / 0.072 avg / 0.505 max
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=139 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=140 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
```

### Send while running

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> = `status` according to `stty -a`.

### Send to one or more known pids

```csh
kill -INFO <pid> [...]
```

### Send to all running

```csh
ps -o comm= -o pid= | egrep '^ping[[:space:]]' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}' | xargs -r kill -INFO
```

### Periodically send to all running

```csh
printf "while ({ sleep 20 })\nps -o comm= -o pid= | egrep '^ping[[:space:]]' | awk -F' ' '{print \0442}' | xargs -r kill -INFO\nend\n" | tcsh
```

#### As a background job

```csh
printf "while ({ sleep 20 })\nps -o comm= -o pid= | egrep '^ping[[:space:]]' | awk -F' ' '{print \0442}' | xargs -r kill -INFO\nend\n" | tcsh &
```

---

## Notes and Thanks

Thank you @pmos for your answer which seeded my idea for the periodic method in the first place, and to all the other answers and comments which contributed to this one.

Thank you @VictorYarema for [making the suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/check-ping-statistics-without-stopping/143853?noredirect=1#comment1074749_143853) that I turn [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/check-ping-statistics-without-stopping/143853?noredirect=1#comment992709_143853) into an actual answer.  The essence of the method in the original comment is the same, but has evolved over time as follows:

- Added the `-r` option to `xargs` to prevent it from running `kill` without a pid when there are no results from `ps`
- To get rid of the header row in `ps` I used the `-o pid=` option to set the column header text to empty instead of `h` since `h` has different meanings for Linux and FreeBSD

  - While `ps` supports the explicit `--no-headers` option in Linux, the same is not true for FreeBSD
- Moved the `sleep` command into the `while` test condition
- Removed unnecessary quotes
- Ported to FreeBSD

  - Thanks to these answers which allowed me to [write a one-liner while loop in tcsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51845409/1861030) which in turn required me to [printf the $](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309791/88754) used in `awk`

Answer (score 6):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

It shows a line like this:

```
312/312 packets, 0% loss, min/avg/ewma/max = 0.312/1.236/0.505/208.655 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ping does not support a useful SIGQUIT (AIX, Solaris), here's one *workaround* -- an infinite ping loop where each ping only fires off (e.g.) 10 pings, so that you can see intermediate results.

```
while :; do ping -c 10 $HOST; done
```

To stop it, <kbd>Control-C</kbd> may only kill the `ping` command; you may need to suspend and then kill the job (<kbd>Control-z</kbd>; `kill %`).

This of course does not provide true running statistics -- just over the course of those 10 pings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use watch utility

```
watch -n 3 ping -c 1 10.170.0.21
```

That will run the `ping` command every 3 seconds and show you the output continuously.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. If you read carefully, the purpose was to have running stats. Running a new `ping` would lose the history and thus not give the desired information.