# How can I echo dollar signs?

Tags: shell, quoting

For example, `$PATH` and `$HOME`

When i type `echo $PATH` it returns my `$PATH`, but i want to echo the word `$PATH` and not what the actual variable stands for, `echo "$PATH"` doesn't work either.

Comment: yes use single quote like : `echo '$PATH'`. for more information about quoting, visit [this](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0060.php) and [this](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting)

Comment: @don only saw a dupe on serverfault. My bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a special character as a normal one?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141/22565)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That question is almost two years newer than this one.

Comment: @DisplayName, yes but is intended as a "canonical" question to cover all those "how to I display special character X". (I'm not sure I like the idea of those "canonical" cover-it-all answers being used to close specific questions though which is why I just added it as a comment instead of a close vote).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Alright.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You just need to escape the dollar `$`.:

```
echo \$PATH
$PATH
```

Or surround it in single quotes:

```
echo '$PATH'
$PATH
```

This will ensure the word is not interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't say anything about `echo -e` on the man page.

Comment: The `-e` flag is used to expand, e.g, `\t` to a literal tab character. It is unrelated to escaping the dollar sign to prevent parameter expansion.

Comment: This doesn't work when directing to a file. `echo '\$PATH' >> output.txt` results in "/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/vc/bin" being written to the file, not "$PATH".

Comment: Very interesting, if you are using single quotes and an escaped character, then that should just echo \$PATH. What OS / package is your echo comand sourced from?

Comment: @Cerin for you @stéphane answer worked `echo '\044*' > first.txt`
it will output $* in first.txt

Answer (score 27):

`$` in the syntax of most shells is a very special character. If we only look at Bourne-like shells it is used to introduce:

1. parameter expansions as in `$#`, `$var`, `${foo:-bar}`
2. command substitution as in `$(logname)` (also `${ logname;}` in some shells to avoid the subshell)
3. arithmetic expansion as in `$((1+1))` (also `$[1+1]` in some shells).
4. other forms of quoting in some shells like `$'\n'` or `$"localized string"`.

Except for the last case, those expansions/substitutions still occur inside double quotes (and inside `$"..."` in `bash` or `ksh93`)

To stop that `$` from being treated specially, you need to quote it with either:

- single quotes: `echo '$PATH'` or `echo '$'PATH`. The one you'd generally want to use as it escapes all characters (except itself) in most shells.
- blackslash: `echo \$PATH`. Also inside double quotes: `echo "\$PATH"`
- in some shells, some other quoting operator: `echo $'$PATH'`, `echo $'\44PATH'` (assuming an ASCII compatible charset), `echo $'\u0024'`

Or make sure it's not part of a valid form of expansion as listed above:

- `echo "$"PATH`
- <strike>`echo $""PATH`, `echo $"PATH"`</strike>. Those should be avoided because some shells like `ksh93` and `bash` support the `$"..."` form of quotes.
- ``` echo $``PATH ```. No reason why you'd want to use that one except to show that it's possible.
- `echo "${$+$}PATH"` and other convoluted ones...

Or you could output that `$` another way:

- with a Unix-compliant `echo`: `echo '\044PATH'` (some other `echo`s need `echo -e '\044PATH'`)
- `printf '\44PATH\n'`
- ```
  cat << \EOF
  $PATH
  EOF
  ```

Note how those backslashes need to be quoted as they also are special to the shell obviously.

Should hopefully be clear by now that although there are many ways to do it, there's no good reason you'd want to use anything else but `echo '$PATH'` here.

Answer (score 2):

Note that literal $ inside double quotes can be a problem. It can be done by producing the $ outside the double quotes, like this:

```
echo "My terminal is $term, first file found in /dev is </dev/`ls /dev | head -n 1`>, the
dollar symbol is '"`echo '$'`"', and a newspaper costs "`echo '$'`"2.50."

or like this:

echo "$term is the value of "'$term'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My terminal is xterm, first file found in /dev is </dev/acpi>, the dollar symbol
is '$', and a newspaper costs $2.50.

xterm is the value of $term
```

Comment: Or `echo "$term is the value of \$term"` as already explained in another answer. Or `printf '%s is the value of $term\n' "$term"` as anyway one shouldn't use `echo` for arbitrary data.

Comment: In Debian `$term` is empty use `$TERM` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
echo ''\$PATH'' >> output.txt
```

This will work.

Comment: please add a comment when down-voting

Comment: Or `ec""h'''o''' ''""''\$P''A""TH''`

Comment: I'm not sure what is being attempted by this answer. The answer is to use either \$ or single quotes. 

echo '$PATH' will print $PATH
echo '\$PATH' will print \$PATH
echo "\$PATH" will print $PATH
echo ''\$PATH'' will technically do the right thing, but the two null strings serve no purpose.

Comment: I dont understand why this answer is downvoted. It is perfectly working fine.