# Echo bracket symbol to terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script

The command `echo Hello World`, prints `Hello World` as expected, but `echo Hello (World)` generates the error `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``.

I'm aware that brackets such as `()`, `{}`, `[]` are tokens and have a special meaning, so how do you "escape" these in a `bash` script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I echo dollar signs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162476/how-can-i-echo-dollar-signs) Or [How do I handle special characters like a bracket in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173851/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-like-a-bracket-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: @Ah yes, those appear to be duplicate, thanks. Would be nice for a combined answer because there appear to be multiple answers: single quotes around whole string, double quotes around whole string, single quote around the special characters and backslash, as in `\(`, and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're not actually tokens in the lexer sense, except for the plain parenthesis `(` and `)`.

`{` and `}` in particular don't need any quoting at all:

```
$ echo {Hello World}
{Hello World}
```

(except if you have `{` or `}` as the first word of a command, where they're interpreted as keywords; or if you have `{a,b}` in a single word with a comma or double-dot in between, where it's a brace expansion.)

`[]` is also only special as a glob characters, and if there are no matching filenames, the default behaviour is to just leave the word as-is.

But anyway, to escape them, you'd usually quote them with single  or double-quotes:

```
echo "(foo bar)"
echo '(foo bar)'
```

Or just escape the relevant characters one-by-one, though that's a bit weary:

```
echo \(foo\ bar\)
```

Or whatever combination you like:

```
echo \(fo"o bar"')'
```

See:

- [What is the difference between "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)
- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0):

Specific to the Q: real "escaping" would be:

`echo hello \(world\)`

A "clean" call of echo with one shell argument is:

`echo "hello (world)"`

...and you get the "escaping" for free.

`echo hello "("world")"`

is quite undefinable. And so on. "you can play with echo".

`"hello $world"` and

`'hello $world'`

are not the same! Use `world=mars` first.

Comment: What do you mean by "undefinable"? `echo hello "("world")"` is quite well defined, being equivalent to `echo hello \(world\)`.

Comment: @chepner Are the parens escaped or quoted? escaped by quoting? You are right, I did not mean the result when I said undefinable.

Comment: Quoting is just a form of mass escaping. Inside double quotes, each character is treated as if it were escaped, with the exception of `$` (and any following characters that form a valid parameter name), `"`, and backslash