# Can I see the summed up results of the ping command while it is running?

Tags: linux, ping

When I run the `ping` command it outputs information for each ping and in the end, when I kill the process it outputs some overall statistics

```
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.275/2.596/7.246/1.870 ms
```

Is there a way to see these statistics while `ping` is running, without having to kill it? I'm particularly interested in continuously monitoring the the packet loss statistic because you need to wait a bit to get accurate numbers for that.

Comment: I don't know of a way, but normally use mtr when I want running statistics like that.

Comment: does your ping support [SIGQUIT](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/check-ping-statistics-without-stopping) ?

Comment: The Q isn't tagged to an OS; I'd vote-to-close for Linux, but AIX & Solaris (for example) simply quit under SIGQUIT.

Comment: If the ping does not support a useful SIGQUIT, my first thought is to create a ping wrapper that runs an infinite (or pass the number) loops to a ping that runs a set count/npackets number of pings in order to give you intermediate results.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I'm on Linux and it does seem to support sigquit so I voted to close this as a duplicate. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press CTRL+\ while ping is running it will display the stats

[Check ping statistics without stopping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/check-ping-statistics-without-stopping)